# Chromium 47.0.2518.0 not loading javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a webpage i'm creating for a home automation system and i can load the project using vs code in chrome desktop, phone, and edge just fine. But for the Chromium 47.0.2518.0 that the android touch-panel is using, i cant get it to load the javascript file

```
<header>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</header>
```

I just dont know what else to try to get this page to load the file. Its loading all the CSS just fine, just not that file.